# Injecting highlight.js to work with vue2-editor (Quill)

Tags: javascript, node.js, quill, highlight.js

I have a trouble connecting vue2-editor (based on quill) with highlight.js

No matter what I do, I get an error saying:

> Syntax module requires highlight.js. Please include the library on the page before Quill.

I'm using nuxt if it changes anything.

I've tried adding this line at the beginning of script tag:

```
import hljs from'highlightjs';
```

So it looks like:

```
<script>
import hljs from'highlightjs';

export default {
  middleware: 'hasPermissions',
  permissions: [ 'createPosts' ],
  ...
}
</script>
```

My plugin where I require vue2-editor:

```
import Vue from'vue';
import VueEditor from'vue2-editor';

Vue.use(VueEditor);
```

VueEditor component in my page:

```
<VueEditor
  class="my-4"
  v-model="content"
  :editor-options="{ modules: { syntax: true } }"
  placeholder="Post content" />
```

EDIT:
I've tried creating my own component and it shows the same error:

```
<template>
  <v-layout
    row
    wrap>
    <v-flex xs12>
      <div ref="editor" />
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import Quill from'quill';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editor: null
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    window.hljs = require('highlight.js');
    this.editor = new Quill(this.$refs.editor, {
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          [{ header: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, false ]}],
          [ 'bold', 'italic', 'underline' ]
        ],
        syntax: true
      },
      theme: 'snow',
      formats: [ 'bold', 'underline', 'header', 'italic' ]
    });

    this.editor.root.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
};
</script>
```

I can successfully print hljs in console in development tools in my browser. What's wrong?

Comment: I had a similar problem when using quill with angular. The problem was that quill was constantly being loaded before highlight.js or that highlight.js was never within scope where quill could access it. In the end I ended up loading highlight.js in the root html (in my case index.html, where angular was injected). You could try it out until you find a better solution.

Comment: What if I register my own component with Quill and HLJS? Maybe i Can avoid using vue2-editor

Comment: Did you install highlightjs?

Answer (score 1):

This one should be a better solution, works for me.
https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor/issues/39

> In fact, this is because quill internal self-closure caused by the
> problem, the solution is as follows: modules.syntax from true to
> replace a function:

```
import hljs from 'highlight.js'
import 'highlight.js/styles/monokai-sublime.css'

editorOption: {
  modules: {
    syntax: {
      highlight: text => hljs.highlightAuto(text).value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a long time too and [this](https://cheerego.github.io/2017/01/21/%E5%9C%A8Vue%E4%B8%AD%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8highlight.js/) answer worked for me!

```
    // highlight.js  component
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hljs from 'highlight.js'
import 'highlight.js/styles/googlecode.css'
let Highlight = {}
Highlight.install = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.directive('highlight', function (el) {
    let blocks = el.querySelectorAll('pre code');
    blocks.forEach((block) => {
      Hljs.highlightBlock(block)
    })
  })
}
export default Highlight

// in main.js

import Highlight from 'path/to/Highlight.js'
Vue.use(Highlight)
```

I changed      `import 'highlight.js/styles/googlecode.css'`
to  `import 'highlight.js/styles/monokai-sublime.css'` seems to be a more popular and pleasing style.
 you could also probably add a

```
hljs.configure({   // optionally configure hljs
  languages: ['javascript', 'ruby', 'python']
});
```

to select certain languages, but I haven't tried.

Although I still haven't figured out how to change the background color. it shows up white in other places and black background in the quill window.